# Capacitor for 5V to 3.3V on AMS1117 voltage regulator?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

I have ESP32 with several modules attached which require 1A 3.3V. I am planning to use 5V 3A power supply which then step down to 3.3V with AMS1117.

How large capacitor need to stabilize AMS1117 input? Is there any capacitor need to stabilize the output?

Because my electronic engineering knowledge is very limited, I am planning to use 4700uf on AMS1117 input and 470uf on the output. Maybe "bigger is better". Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We ask that prior to asking a question you do a bit of searching for yourself and then ask if you have a question about any confusion or issues. Datasheet: http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf

Comment: What does the datasheet tell you?  The datasheet should have all of the information that you need to decide what capacitor values are required.  Please check the datasheet, then modify your question by asking specific questions about what you don't understand when you read the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the AMS1117 datasheet,](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) you need a 22uF capacitor on the output to guarantee stability under all conditions.

It recommends a 22uF solid tantalum capacitor.  Those tend to make people nervous because tantalum capacitors tend to explode and/or catch fire if they are accidentally operated outside their normal operating conditions (particularly if exposed to over voltage or reverse voltage.)

The "typical adjustable regulator" circuit from figure 2 of page 3 of the datasheet does show a capacitor on the input, but other wise doesn't mention it.  It probably isn't needed for normal operation, but you should probably include one if the power leads to the regulator are long (say, 1uF as recommended for the old 7805 if the input leads are over 12 inches long.)

Comment: Solid tantalum recommendations for linear regulators make me nervous as the part *may* need some minimum ESR (some older tantalums tended to have an ESR that was suitable, in the couple of ohms range)

Answer (score 3):

The [datasheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) does not endorse the use of a ceramic capacitor on the output, and from that omission I would be very nervous about using such (even though numerous Chinese hobby products ignore this concern). If you do want to use a ceramic type on the output it would be much safer to add a small amount of resistance (perhaps 1-2 ohms) in series. Also keep in mind that ceramic capacitors can lose much of their capacitance under bias, so check that the ceramic part is roughly in the 22uF range under bias.

> The circuit design used in the AMS1117 series requires the use of
>   an output capacitor as part of the device frequency compensation.
>   The addition of 22µF solid tantalum on the output will ensure
>   stability for all operating conditions.
>   When the adjustment terminal is bypassed with a capacitor to
>   improve the ripple rejection, the requirement for an output
>   capacitor increases. The value of 22µF tantalum covers all cases of
>   bypassing the adjustment terminal. Without bypassing the
>   adjustment terminal smaller capacitors can be used with equally
>   good results.
>   To further improve stability and transient response of these
>   devices larger values of output capacitor can be used.

Judging by the values you mention, you are thinking of electrolytic capacitors, which typically (for general purpose types) have acceptably high values of ESR such that they won't negatively impact stability, however very low-Z electrolytic capacitors may have m\$\Omega\$ ESR and could cause instability under some load/input/temperature conditions.

The input capacitor is of much less concern, and your suggested value should be okay from the point of view of the regulator (presumably it's also the filter capacitor so you'll have to make sure the regulator gets enough headroom to operate under all conditions). If your input is **regulated** 5V you don't need anything like that large capacitance on the input. A 1uF ceramic near the part is fine.